# Problem with C nested structure. error: invalid use of incomplete typedef

Tags: c, struct, nested

For the sake of simplicity I'm going to recreate the actual situation with dummy structures. I have this structure (not my code, I can't edit it):

```
// private_header_a.h
struct A_s{
 int a1;
};
// header_a.h
typedef struct A_s A_t;
```

Then in one of my headers I extended it this way:

```
// my_header.h
typedef struct B_s{
 A_t* a_f;
 int b1;
} B_t;
```

Now, in my function, I have:

```
B_t* b;
// Initialization and some other code
b->b1 = 4; // Just an example and compiler does not give any error
// Some other code
b->a_f->a1;
```

This last line of code makes the compiler throw this error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘A_t’ {aka ‘struct A_s’}
```

Where is the error?
EDIT: the piece of code that triggers the compiler has `header_a.h` and `my_header.h` included. `private_header_a.h` cannot be included directly as not installed (I should copy-paste it, but frankly I would like to avoid to do that)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't include the header that defines `struct A_s` in the file with the function.

Comment: There is not enough information without knowing which lines of code appear in which header files and where the `#include` directives are located. Please add this information to the question.

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't work :\.

Comment: @IanAbbott edited

Comment: You're sure the struct definition is in the public header and the typedef in the private header, not the other way around? In that case it seems you wouldn't be able to name `A_t` at all.

Comment: @aschepler yes, I'm an idiot. I edited correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error is probably intentional - the library's designers don't want you using `A_t` directly in that sort of way.

When a struct is only declared in a library's public header file, and only defined in the library's private implementation files, that means you're not supposed to know or care about its members or even size. So looking up that the struct has a member named `a1` and writing `b->af->a1` is not the intended use. This arrangement is called an "opaque handle". A few of its benefits are that the library keeps your application code from initializing or changing members in ways that don't make sense, and a future version of the library can change the names, numbers, and meanings of the members without breaking your application code.

(Also, how did you get a valid pointer for `b->af` without doing `malloc(sizeof(A_t))` or similar? That `sizeof` would also cause a compiler error about the incomplete struct type.)

When a library uses an opaque handle, since you can't create any such objects yourself, it will typically provide functions that create the objects for you. Look for public functions in the library with names including `init`, `create`, `open`, etc. which return an `A_t*` pointer, and read their documentation. Usually there will also be a corresponding `destroy`, `cleanup`, `close`, etc. function which the program should call later when the library object is no longer needed. (In the case of some very simple handles, the function which creates the object might say instead you should just pass the pointer to `free`. But only do this if the documentation says to!)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I'm realizing. without too much details, the point is that the library does not provide method to initialize all the members as I want (it only provides some method to set them in some significant arrangements. I think I must copy-past the definitions ahah

Comment: Okay. I'd consider also asking on the library's issue tracker or mailing list for a future enhancement that would solve the problem making your "cheat" necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's two fundamental rules:

1. Each c file is compiled separately
2. When you #include a file, think of it as directly replacing the #include line with the contents of the file being included.

Therefore, you are compiling a piece of source code that looks like this:

```
struct A_s {
 int a1;
};

typedef struct B_s {
 A_t* a_f;
 int b1;
} B_t;

void foo() {
  B_t* b;
}
```

This code doesn't know what `A_t` is. You've never defined that in the code that's visible to the compiler.

A trivial way to fix this is to replace `A_t` with `struct A_s`.